# core data migration issue: storePath cannot be initiated

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I tried to migrate some core data code from swift 2 to swift 4. The code is below:

```
///  Removes the existing model store specfied by the receiver.
///
///  - returns: A tuple value containing a boolean to indicate success and an error object if an error occurred.
public func removeExistingModelStore() -> (success: Bool, error: NSError?) {
    var error: NSError?
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if let storePath = storeURL.path {
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: storePath) {
            let success: Bool
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: storeURL)
                success = true
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                success = false
            }
            if !success {
                print("*** \(String(describing: CoreDataModel.self)) ERROR: [\(#line)] \(#function) Could not remove model store at url: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
            return (success, error)
        }
    }

    return (false, nil)
}
```

The building error says "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'". So I googled and followed the suggestion to remove optional binding:

```
let storePath = storeURL.path { ... }
```

Then it has two new errors at the above spot: 1. Cannot call value of non-function type 'String'; 2. Variable used within its own initial value

I believe the codes above are mostly boilerplate codes for setup/teardown core data models. I'm a beginner so please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you removed `if` from `if let` , then you have to remove `{ }` also , You can try

```
public func removeExistingModelStore() -> (success: Bool, error: Error?) {

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: storeURL.path ) {

        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: storeURL)
             return (true, nil) 
        } catch {

            return (false, error)  
        }

     } 

    return (false, nil)
}
```